# Is there an API or global source for US ballot information?

Tags: usa, elections

I'd like to be able to query to discover what's on the ballot - from local measures to Presidential elections.

Is there a source that combines all of this data?  Or is there a standard that's relatively well implemented in the majority of locations that can be leveraged?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several sources of this kind of information:

- [Ballotpedia](http://ballotpedia.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) - lots of information, but in wiki pages, so not well-structured/API-able.
- [The Ballot Information Project](http://neworganizingeducation.com/project/BIP) - an NOI project; a fair bit of data, structured (with an API, I think?)
- [The Voting Information Project](https://votinginfoproject.org/) - this one has big sponsors (Google, etc.), and has an API as well.
- [Project Votesmart](http://votesmart.org/) - Used to be the place to go for this kind of thing, but now charges for their data; still, they have a lot of stuff and could be a fallback, depending on whether the other sources have what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you are simply looking for information that can be found on the ballot I think [Google's Civic API](https://developers.google.com/civic-information/docs/us_v1/elections/voterInfoQuery) is your best bet. Specifically the `Contests` section.